# Implicit cast to char* when calling printf

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, printf, variadic-functions

I'm using Unicode strings as icons in my C++ GUI application and wanted to get rid of all the `u8"\uf118"` magic strings I had splattered around, and on the way, make these strings a type of their own.

So I created a class like this:

```
struct icon
{
    explicit constexpr icon(const char (&unicode_icon)[4]) :
        _icon{ unicode_icon[0], unicode_icon[1], unicode_icon[2], unicode_icon[3] }
    {
    }
    operator const char*() const
    {
        return _icon.data();
    }
private:
    std::array<char, 5> _icon;
};
```

And the GUI library uses some form of `printf` (I think `vfprintf`)
So the code calls:

```
icon smiley { u8"\uf118" };
printf("%s", smiley);
```

I was testing this on windows so far and it worked great, but when I compile it on Linux with gcc (5.1) I get the following warning:

```
main.cpp:22:24: warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char*', but argument 2 has type 'icon' [-Wformat=]
     printf("%s", smiley);
```

[Live example here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/58df68702c9807fb)

And when I run it, I get a seg fault inside `vfprintf` since it is not using the cast operator I provided.

I know I can explicitly cast the icon when I pass it to the GUI library (which has the following prototype `(const char* fmt, ...)` but this will make me write even more code and, well, it will look worse.

Is there a way to make the compiler do the magic and allow me to call the function like this: `printf("%s", smiley);` (or some other simple way)?

Comment: Um, why? Why do you need the class? Why not `const char* smiley = u8"\uf118";`?

Comment: If it worked on Windows, it was just an accident and doesn't necessarily work tomorrow.

Comment: Or, in a pinch, `const std::string smiley{u8"\uf118"};` These things are strings after all.

Comment: `printf()` is a variable arguments function.   The format specifier tells the function how to interpret the corresponding argument it receives.   It doesn't tell the compiler to do a conversion to the specified type in order to pass an object as an argument.

Comment: @n.m. `const std::string smiley` adds runtime overhead to the code which was previously just `printf("%s", u8"\uf118")`

Comment: @Peter, right, I assume VC has a cast inside their implementation of printf which makes it work

Comment: "adds runtime overhead" So? Have you measured it? Does it have a non-negligible impact on your application? Stop worrying about nonsense and get your programs simple and readable.

Comment: @n.m. what's more readable than `icon smiley` ?

Comment: @n.m. Also - using `std::string` would require me to add `.c_str()` every call, so I guess I could have had `const char* smiley = u8"\uf118";` but I wanted a type safe way to use icons

Comment: `std::string smiley` is of course more readable. I don't know what an `icon` is. Am I dealing with a GUI?

Comment: If you want to be type safe, perhaps consider replacing `printf` with C++ type safe IO. There's hardly anything *less* type safe than `printf`.

Comment: @n.m. Yes it is a GUI, and I can't change the use of `printf` since it is a 3rd party library I use, as I wrote. And it is actually named `textual_icon` in my code so it is pretty obvious what it represents

Comment: It is pretty obvious to you perhaps. I wouldn't know what to do with a thing called "textual icon".

Comment: @n.m you probably would not have known what to do with a `scope_guard` too just by looking at the name

Comment: scope_guard is in the standard, and is used by everyone. textual_icon, to put it bluntly, is not. anyway, I don't see how this type is in any way more safe or readable or anything than `const char*`. you are welcome to use it if you see the point, I don't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Varargs functions isn't very well-handled by C++. Most importantly, there's no implicit casting of objects since the compiler can't (in the general case) know what type is really expected.

The best solution is to *not* use vararg functions if there are alternatives. And for `printf` and friends there are (for `printf` it's `std::cout`).

If you for some reason still need to use vararg functions (for example because you use a C library) then the only solution is to explicitly cast the objects. In your case it would be `static_cast<const char*>(smiley)`.

Comment: Another variant would be to have a `c_str()` member (as `std::string` does).

Comment: Microsoft 's `CString` uses a layout with `char*` as first member to allow `printf` to work without cast, but they also say you better cast it to get the expected result - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa296561(v=vs.60).aspx

Comment: @A.A That is also *very* implementation-specific, and depends very much on how varargs are implemented by the compiler.

Comment: I agree with this answer but I don't want to accept it yet since maybe someone will come up with a nifty workaround or some other simple way

Comment: The other alternative is a variadic template implementation of printf, where each argument could make use of its casting operations to int, char*, or detect an operator << implementation. Actually, it would be quite easy to implement a version of printf on std::ostream that utilised operator <<

Comment: I ended up adding an overload to the gui function that takes an `icon` and calls the original API with a static cast...